# Changing context element dynamically regarding some condition in Sitecore CMS

Tags: sitecore

I have user control under Sitecore CMS. It has some controls bound to some fields of context. For example:

```xml
<sc:text runat="server" field="HomePage_WelcomeText"></sc:text>
```

I have different content items based on the same template and I need to change context to some of them in PageLoad(). For example, if URLRefferer has certain value I want to have certain content item in context.

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sc:text` control has a public property called `Item` that takes a `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item`. So, give your control an ID attribute, then on `Page_Load` you can dynamically set that Item property as needed.

```xml
<sc:text id="myTextControl" runat="server" field="HomePage_WelcomeText" />
```

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Sitecore.Data.Items.Item myItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home");
    myTextControl.Item = myItem;
}
```